# completion-ignored-filenames?

Tags: completion, find-file

Is there a way to do ignore whole file names the same way as
'completion-ignored-extensions' ignores filename extensions?

For example, I would like to blacklist `__pycache__/`, so that if the default directory contains `__init__.py` and `__pycache__/` (and these two are the only files whose names start with underscore), I can do `C-x C-f _ TAB` and get right to `__init__.py` as the only choice, without Emacs offering me `__pycache__/` after me hitting `TAB` once more to reveal the second underscore.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what the context of your question is. If you're using function `read-file-name` then you can pass it a `PREDICATE` argument that will exclude any files or dirs you want to exclude as completion candidates. `C-h f read-file-name` tells us:

> Sixth arg `PREDICATE`, if non-`nil`, should be a function of one
> argument; then a file name is considered an acceptable completion
> alternative only if `PREDICATE` returns non-`nil` with the file name
> as its argument.

So a `PREDICATE` value of `foo` would exclude file `__pycache__`:

```lisp
(defun foo (filename)
  "Return non-nil if FILENAME is not `__pycache__'."
  (setq filename  (directory-file-name filename))
  (not (string= filename "__pycache__")))

(read-file-name "File: " nil nil t nil 'foo)
```

The reason for using `directory-file-name` is so that this works for a `FILENAME` value that is a directory name, as well as a value that is an ordinary file name.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `completion-ignored-extensions`

```
It ignores directory names if they match any string in this list which
ends in a slash.
```

so you can simply add `__pycache__/` to the variable

```
(add-to-list 'completion-ignored-extensions
             "__pycache__/")
```